# disable a row in a grouped grid Ext Js

Tags: extjs, grid

This paragraph is translated from French.

I'm really stuck. my problem in my application is as follows:

I am currently developing an implementation Ext js. I would like to disable rows in a grouped grid. I use Ext.Fly function (() getNodes grid.getView () [index Store].) mask ().;

except that when the group in my inner gate is closed (collapsed). Ext.fly the statement returns a error (Ext.fly is null).

I wonder if there is a way to disable a row in a grouped grid other than Ext.fly.

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: Please provide the code for what you are doing.

Comment: var  nodes = grid.getEl().query('.x-grid-data-row'); Ext.get(nodes[nodeIndex]).mask();  or i can use this :               var nodes = grid.getView().getNodes(); Ext.fly(nodes[nodeIndex]).mask();                                   I have the same error in both codes when the group of my grid are collaped.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps please try 
Use grid beforeselect event to disable selection, view getRowClass method to style row .

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, index) {
// disabled-row - custom css class for disabled (you must declare it)
            if (record.get('name') == disabled_name) return 'disabled-row';
        }        
    },

    listeners: {
        beforeselect: function (sm, record) {
            if (record.get('name') == disabled_name) return false;
        }
    },
```

Hope this helps you.
Below link might help you as well
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?208836-Gridpanel-Row-Disable

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 

No, it does not solve my problem. 

When I have a group that is closed and I want to disable an element of this group, I get an error (ext.fly is null). I used Ext.get and it does not work. this is a serious bug ....